# Is uploading files in default /tmp folder an security vulnerability?

Tags: apache2, tmp

I am running Ubuntu with apache on a server.
I want to experiment with uploading files to the server using POST.
In php.ini you can set the folder to use when uploading files.
The default is to use the /tmp folder from the system.

My question: **Is using the standard /tmp folder an security vulnerability?**

Could some data be compromised or changed to use the /tmp folder as temporary folder?

Comment: If you do not have it please bookmark: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet):

> **Session Management**
>
> PHP's default session facilities are considered safe, the generated PHPSessionID is random enough, but the storage is not necessarily safe:
>
> - Session files are stored in temp (/tmp) folder and are world writable **unless suPHP installed**, so any LFI or other leak might end-up manipulating them.

Same applies to files you store in `/tmp/` yourself.

---

More reading:

- [What are the dangers of storing webserver temp files in the /tmp/ folder?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11606/what-are-the-dangers-of-storing-webserver-temp-files-in-the-tmp-folder)